# Run a separate task if the parent task fails in airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a series of tasks in an airflow DAG as below:

task1:
//do something

task2:
//do something

task3:
//do something

task4:
//do cleanup

task1 >> task2 >>task3

**ASK:** I want to run task4 if any of task1 or task2 fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Trigger Rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.9/concepts.html#trigger-rules). Here is an example:

```
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='Ab_sin',
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval=None,
)


with TaskGroup(group_id='ignore_task_4', dag=dag) as ignore_task_4:
    task1 = BashOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task1', bash_command='echo "task1"')
    task2 = BashOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task2', bash_command='echo "task2"')
    task3 = BashOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task3', bash_command='echo "task3"')
    task4 = BashOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task4', bash_command='echo "task4"', trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED)

    task1 >> task2 >> task3
    task4.set_upstream([task1, task2])


with TaskGroup(group_id='run_task_4', dag=dag) as run_task_4:
    task1 = BashOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task1', bash_command='lets say first task was failed')
    task2 = BashOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task2', bash_command='echo "task2"')
    task3 = BashOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task3', bash_command='echo "task3"')
    task4 = BashOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task4', bash_command='echo "task4"', trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED)

    task1 >> task2 >> task3
    task4.set_upstream([task1, task2])
```

[image: demo DAG]